# Angular 6 Typescript extract element from array and compare

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workers-edit',
  templateUrl: './workers-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workers-edit.component.css']
})
export class WorkersEditComponent implements OnInit {
  public workerid;
  public lastname;
  public address;
  public phone;
  public email;

  workers = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.workerid = id;

    let Workerobs = this.http.get('http://myurlPP/cfcs/workernameapi.cfm');
    Workerobs.subscribe((res:any)=> {
      console.log(res);
      this.workers = res;

    });

  }

}
```

The workers array after this contains the following:
[image]

In my html, if I do this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let name of workers">{{name.WNAME}}</li>
</ul>
```

I will get all the names from the array and display them, which is okay.

But I need to display only the name with the matching `workerid`. (I have the workerid at because of     `let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')); this.workerid = id;`

**So how can I extract from the workers array the *WID*, compare it to *workerid*, if it is true, display only the *WNAME* (worker name)** ?

Comment: Can't you just filter in Workerobs.subscribe method itself with res.filter(......) ??

Comment: NOT use a filter NOR *ngFor, use find and a variable this.myuser=workers.find(w=>w.id==id);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter your array inside `subscribe` function

```
Workerobs.subscribe((res:any)=> {
    console.log(res);
    this.workers = res.filter(item => item.WID === this.workerid);
});
```

Maybe property names will be misstype in the `filter` function, so adjust them for your case.

Comment: This works! But can you please explain how does item know what to refer to ? I don't quite understand how this works

Comment: We pass an arrow function to it. `filter` function will iterate over all items in the `res` and apply passed function like `myPassedFunction(res[i])` something like this. The passed parameter will be visible in the function as `item`

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.workerid = id;

    let Workerobs = this.http.get('http://myurlPP/cfcs/workernameapi.cfm');
    Workerobs.subscribe((res:any)=> {
      console.log(res);
      this.workers = res.filter((worker) => worker.id === this.workerid);
    });

  }
```

All you need to do is filter the workers array as above.

Answer (score 0):

Do the below codes, to get your required functionality:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let name of workers">
        <ng-container *ngIf="name.WID == this.workerid">{{name.WNAME}}</ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This much should help you do the trick. Please ask if need any changes in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that cleanly in your `UI` too, just by adding an `*ngIf="condition"` :

```
<ul>
   <li *ngIf="worker.WID == workerid" *ngFor="let worker of workers">{{worker.WNAME}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know Worker ID is unique you should use `find` instead of `filter`, as it will return the first matching item in the array.

```
  selectedWorker: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.workerid = id;

    let Workerobs = this.http.get('http://myurlPP/cfcs/workernameapi.cfm');
    Workerobs.subscribe((res:any)=> {
      this.selectedWorker = res.find((worker) => worker.workerid === this.workerid);
      if (this.selectedWorker === undefined) {
         console.log('no worker with id:' + id + ' was found'
      }
    });
```